# Same queries in PostgreSQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, stored-procedures

So, I'm trying to create a procedure that is going to find
a specific row in my table, save the row in a result to be
returned, delete the row and afterwards return the result.

The best thing I managed to do was the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sth(foo integer)
RETURNS TABLE(a integer, b integer, ... other fields) AS $$
DECLARE
    to_delete_id integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO to_delete_id FROM my_table WHERE sth_id = foo LIMIT 1;
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE sth_id = foo LIMIT 1;

    DELETE FROM my_table where id = to_delete_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As you see, I have 2 `SELECT` operations that pretty much do the same thing (extra
overhead). Is there a way to just have the second `SELECT` and also set the `to_delete_id`
so I can delete the row afterwards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just want a [DELETE...RETURNING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html).

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE sth_id=foo LIMIT 1 RETURNING *
```

Edit based on ahwnn's comment. Quite right too - teach me to cut + paste the query without reading it properly.

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = (SELECT id ... LIMIT 1) RETURNING *
```

Comment: `DELETE` doesn't support `LIMIT`

Comment: The second solution seems to pretty much do 2 `SELECT's` in the sense that you first select the id and then you search to delete the table with this id. I just want to `SELECT` and delete immediately.

Comment: But unless I misunderstood your example, you're not trying to delete all the matches, just one (at random)

Comment: Richard ... not really. I forgot to add an 'ORDER BY' I have on my code, so I want to delete only the first element after ordering

Comment: Anyway, accepted your solution as the one most close to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done much easier:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sth(foo integer)
RETURNS SETOF my_table
AS
$$
BEGIN
    return query
      DELETE FROM my_table p
      where sth_id = foo
      returning *;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select all the columns into variables, return them, then delete using the id:

Declare a variables for each column (named by convention the save as the column but with a leading underscore), then:

```
SELECT id, col1, col2, ...
INTO _id, _col1, _col22, ...
FROM my_table
WHERE sth_id = foo
LIMIT 1;

RETURN QUERY SELECT _id, _col1, _col22, ...;

DELETE FROM my_table where id = _id;
```